# Having issues with count accumulator regarding returning the count of positive odd integers

Tags: python

I have the following problem statement:

> Write a function odd_finder(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j) which takes 10 integers as inputs and returns the count of positive odd integers.  For instance, if the 10 integers inputted by the user are 1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,0 then output by the function will be 3 (3 positive odd integers: 1,3 and 5).

I wrote this code:

```
def odd_finder(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j):
    count = 0
    for number in range(10):
        if(number % 2 != 0 & number >= 0):
            count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

For the example input, my code prints `5` instead of the correct answer of `3`. What is wrong with the code? I'm not sure if the issue is with my range or with the operator for evaluating positive integers as number > 0 prints overall count of 0.

Comment: You are not using  the values `a` through `j`.

Comment: Instead of getting the values from `range`, you need to do it for values from `a`, through `j`, rest of the logic seems fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you think `&` does in Python? Now, what does it say `&` does in Python, when you look it up? How does it say you should implement a boolean AND logical condition? Also: in your own words, what do you think `range(10)` actually means? When you write `def odd_finder(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j):`, what do you think is the significance of the `(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)` part? If you want to *use those values*, what should you do?

Comment: "or with the operator for positive integers as number > 0 prints count of 0." I don't understand what you mean by this.

Answer (score 1):

There are some **issues** with the function you have written:

1. You are taking values `a` through `j` as parameter, but not using them, you are just using the values coming from `range(10)` which will always be `0` through `9` no matter what are the values passed to the function for `a` through `j`.
2. You are combining the conditions using bitwise and operator `&`, which has higher precedence than `!=`, and `>=`, take a look at [precedence table](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)
3. You are comparing against zero `number >= 0` which will be true for `number=0`, but 0 is not an odd integer.

A modified version of the function would look something like this:

```py
def odd_finder(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j):
    numbers = (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)  #Create a sequence to iterate
    count = 0
    for number in numbers: #range(10):
        if(number % 2 != 0 and number > 0):
            count = count + 1
    print(count)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
>>> odd_finder(1,2,3,4,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,0)
3
```

The first issue is fixed by creating a sequence from the values `a` through `j` in order to iterate these values. You can then replace `range(10)` by iterating `numbers`

The second issue is fixed by replacing bitwise and operator `&` by logical `and` operator

The third issue is fixed by using greater than operator `>` in place of greater than or equal to `>=`

Comment: The specification requires the parameters be that way, silly as it is. You can work around this by explicitly creating the tuple `(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)` within the function.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, Yeah that is silly but True. I just updated the solution.

Comment: The `>` vs `>=` issue doesn't actually matter. Sure, `0` is not positive, but it's also not odd, so the `% 2` check will eliminate it from consideration.